# Foreground Object Region Extraction using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, extract, image-segmentation, object-detection

I am trying to mask a foreground paper object, to afterwards detect it's contours and extract the warped image of the object (segmentation).

My main problem is at the mask/segmentation process.

Extraction is to be done on smartphones (on android), and in most scenarios, the object is always present at the center of the image.

The actual approach i am using, is to use a couple of seed points in the center of the image (based on a minimum size beetween theese points), and floodfill its area:

```
public final static Mat getCenterMask(Mat src, int height, int width, double minLineSize) {

    int newMaskVal = 255;
    Scalar newVal = new Scalar( 255, 0, 0 );

    int connectivity = 8;
    int flags = connectivity + (newMaskVal << 8 ) + Imgproc.FLOODFILL_FIXED_RANGE +Imgproc.FLOODFILL_MASK_ONLY;

    int lo = 25; int up = 25;
    Mat mask2 = Mat.zeros( height + 2, width + 2, CvType.CV_8UC1 );

    Point tmp = new Point(width/2, height/2);
    Point tmp1 = new Point(width/2-minLineSize, height/2);
    Point tmp2 = new Point(width/2+minLineSize, height/2);
    Point tmp3 = new Point(width/2, height/2-minLineSize);
    Point tmp4 = new Point(width/2, height/2+minLineSize);
    Point tmp5 = new Point(width/2-minLineSize, height/2-minLineSize);
    Point tmp6 = new Point(width/2+minLineSize, height/2+minLineSize);
    Point tmp7 = new Point(width/2-minLineSize, height/2+minLineSize);
    Point tmp8 = new Point(width/2+minLineSize, height/2-minLineSize);

    try{
        Imgproc.floodFill(src, mask2, tmp, newVal, null, new Scalar(lo,lo,lo), new Scalar(up,up,up), flags);
        Imgproc.floodFill(src, mask2, tmp1, newVal, null, new Scalar(lo,lo,lo), new Scalar(up,up,up), flags);
        Imgproc.floodFill(src, mask2, tmp2, newVal, null, new Scalar(lo,lo,lo), new Scalar(up,up,up), flags);
        Imgproc.floodFill(src, mask2, tmp3, newVal, null, new Scalar(lo,lo,lo), new Scalar(up,up,up), flags);
        Imgproc.floodFill(src, mask2, tmp4, newVal, null, new Scalar(lo,lo,lo), new Scalar(up,up,up), flags);
        Imgproc.floodFill(src, mask2, tmp5, newVal, null, new Scalar(lo,lo,lo), new Scalar(up,up,up), flags);
        Imgproc.floodFill(src, mask2, tmp6, newVal, null, new Scalar(lo,lo,lo), new Scalar(up,up,up), flags);
        Imgproc.floodFill(src, mask2, tmp7, newVal, null, new Scalar(lo,lo,lo), new Scalar(up,up,up), flags);
        Imgproc.floodFill(src, mask2, tmp8, newVal, null, new Scalar(lo,lo,lo), new Scalar(up,up,up), flags);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        return null;
    }

    Mat thresh = mask2.submat(new Range(1, mask2.rows()-1), new Range(1, mask2.cols()-1));

    /** Eliminate small components **/
    Imgproc.dilate(thresh, thresh, new Mat(), new Point(-1, -1), 1);
    Imgproc.erode(thresh, thresh, new Mat(), new Point(-1, -1), 1);
    return thresh;
}
```

In about 50% of the scenarios i get good results, but it fails when lightning conditions vary or color similar objects are sticked to the object (i.e. hand).

Here are a few of good results (good masks), were i can extract my object with no problem.

### Good Results

Input Image

[image]
[image]

Mask

[image]
[image]

Final Region Detection

[image]
[image]

Here are a few of bad results.

The mask it generates is very bad to extract the complete rectangular object.

### Bad Results

Input Image

[image]
[image]

Mask

[image]
[image]

Is it possible to enhance my approach?

Are there other better aprroaches, using maybe morphological filters?

Comment: One idea may be to look at [Histogram Equalization](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_equalization/histogram_equalization.html) on the bad images.

Comment: Do some pre- and post-processing should help. Why not give it a shot first? After all you've mentioned morphological filters. Btw, is your foreground object moving? If so, have you tried MoG?